# DSDM Atern or DSDM?

Tags: agile, dsdm

Is the methodology named DSDM or DSDM Atern?
A colleague and I are writing reports on agile methodologies and there is a lot of conflicting information available as the latest specification we could find makes no reference of Atern but the DSDM consortium's website still says DSDM Atern on it. Any sources are welcomed.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a question about project management as defined in [ask]

Answer (score 2):

From the [DSDM entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_systems_development_method) in wikipedia:

> In 2014, DSDM dropped the branding 'Atern' and reverted to its
>   original name in the latest version of the method in the 'DSDM Agile
>   Project Framework' positioned as "an ideal wrapper for more limited
>   Agile frameworks.